# Cypress: Running Test using custom TZ value in Windows

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows, cypress

I had my tests designed to be run in an environment which assumed to be in UTC.

I used cy.clock() to set a date-time in UTC format. The Web App to test will display current browser date-time in UTC format.

I had TZ=UTC in my environment variables and I run my test in Cypress Runner in Linux machine using TZ=UTC npx cypress open. The date and the time display on the web app is same as the date time I set using cy.clock()

However, the same method seems doesn't work in Windows. I couldn't use TZ=UTC npx cypress open in Windows. Instead I used npx cypress open. The time is correct but the date differs by one day. If I change my windows pc timezone to UTC, the both date and time is as expected.

Is there any other way other than change the computer timezone in Windows ? I do not need to do so in Linux

My tests runs fine in CI without the need for TZ before the script. Setting it in environment variable in cypress.json is sufficient.

Can someone please enlightened me on this please ?

My cypress.json

```
{
    "projectId": "blahblahbah",
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
    "numTestsKeptInMemory": 10,
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "TZ": "UTC",
    "env": {
        "BASE_URL": "http://localhost:4200",
        "TZ": "UTC",
    },
    "integrationFolder": "cypress/tests/",
    "retries": {
        "runMode": 2,
        "openMode": 0
    },
    "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
    "reporterOptions": {
        "charts": true,
        "reportPageTitle": "XXXX Test",
        "embeddedScreenshots": true,
        "inlineAssets": true,
        "reportDir": "cypress/reports/",
        "timestamp": "mmddyyyy_HHMMss"
    },
    "video": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround in Windows other than setting your computer clock.

You can use WSL2 to run Linux command in Windows 11. If you do not have Windows 11, update it. If your computer cannot support Windows 11, buy a new one.

**Make sure you are in Windows 11 Build 22000**

1. Install Docker. Followed the instruction to get Docker running successfully. That also includes setting up WSL2. In this step you will be directed to Microsoft guide to install WSL 2 and install a Linux distro from Microsoft Store. Make sure you did RESTART

Install driver for vGPU

- Intel GPU driver for WSL
- AMD GPU driver for WSL
- NVIDIA GPU driver for WSL

Links can be obtained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

After that Open Powershell as Admin

wsl --update followed by wsl --shutdown

RESTART COMPUTER

---

Follow the below sub-steps if you wish to try to luck or increase chances of success.

Can do this for non Windows 11 PC

a. Install VcXsrv
(Multiple windows and Start no client is recommended)
On the page that lets you enable extra settings, disable access control
b. In VSCode, open project folder and a new terminal using dropdown. (There is a + button) Look for Ubuntu (WSL). Here you have access to the bash shell.
c. Type the following command in sequence

```
set DISPLAY variable to the IP automatically assigned to WSL2
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
```

```
echo $DISPLAY
# expect something like 192.168.64.1:0.0
```

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start &> /dev/null
```

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/dbus
```

After this command, an editor will launch. Add the following line with your distro username.
<your_username> ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/dbus

Remember to set permission in firewall to allow VcXsrv on domain, private and public network.

RESTART COMPUTER

---

2. In VSCode, open project folder and a new terminal using dropdown. (There is a + button) Look for Ubuntu (WSL). Here you have access to the bash shell.
3. Install cypress dependencies by using

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb
```

5. Install npm and nodejs by using
   '''
   sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
   '''

Note: Prior to 3 and . It is assumed that you have already done apt-get update

1. npm i
2. Open another New Terminal ( Ubuntu WSL) to run npm serve
3. You can attempt to

```
 npx cypress open
```

to see if it works well.

Remember npm serve, npm i and npx cypress open need to be in bash ( Ubuntu WSL)

If you are using Windows 11 Build 22000 and above, you can try to exit  VcXsrv, and do npx cypress open again. I tried and it still work.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps
https://shouv.medium.com/how-to-run-cypress-on-wsl2-989b83795fb6

**ANOTHER KISS SOLUTION: USE GIT BASH**

Just launch Git Bash from VSCODE followed by TZ=UTC npx cypress open

Answer (score 1):

I think the Windows equiv to `TZ=UTC npx cypress open` is `set TZ=UTC && npx cypress open`.

There's also [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), allows a single script to work across different OS.

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "cy:open": "cross-env TZ=UTC npx cypress open"
  }
}
```

But it seems to be fussy about the shell

> **Windows Issues**
> Please note that npm uses cmd by default and that doesn't support command substitution, so if you want to leverage that, then you need to update your .npmrc to set the script-shell to powershell.

Another option is [run-script-os](https://github.com/charlesguse/run-script-os)

See [Run different NPM scripts depending on the platform](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/npm-tips-and-tricks/#run-different-npm-scripts-depending-on-the-platform)

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "run-script-os",
    "test:win32": "set TZ=UTC && npx cypress open",
    "test:darwin:linux": "TZ=UTC npx cypress open",
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me